# "reload" mac audio drivers without rebooting

Tags: macos, mac, audio, drivers

I have an external audio interface (M-audio fast track c400). In order to get my macbook to recognize it (display in audio/midi setup), I have to reboot, which is a hassle. I have had other m-audio interfaces that were automatically detected when connected, and I'm pretty sure this one should be the same. Most posts around the internet suggest updating the OS or the software/firmware for the device. I have done all of those with no luck. I am currently running OS X 10.8.5.

Is there a way to force OS X to reload the device? Preferably some command line voodoo that I could fire off quickly when needed or wrap up in a nice little shell script.

#### Edit: Progress..

The problem appears to be fixed now... I'm not sure how the following solved the problem. If you know, please comment!

Inspired by @sbugert's answer, I started looking into other system daemon's that might do the trick if restarted. As a shot in the dark I killed `coreservicesd`. This caused the OS to become visibly unstable and I was eventually logged out automatically. To my surprise, when I logged back in, my audio interface was recognized..

Based on that, I hypothesized that killing `coreservicesd` and logging out/in may be a possible (ugly) workaround. So I unplugged the interface and plugged it back in, and as expected, it was not recognized. So I killed coreservicesd and attempted to log out, however I could not get the system to log out due to the instability caused by killing coreservicesd. I eventually was forced to do a "hard" shutdown (i.e. holding the power button until it turns off). After booting up the macbook again, the interface is now recognized automatically every time I plug it in. I suspect that this "hard" reset may have solved the issue without all the shenanigans with the coreservices daemon, but I have no way to test that.

If anyone can shed light on this, please do!

#### Edit: It stopped working again so I don't know what's up.

Answer (score 121, accepted):

EDIT: most likely only works for osx before 10.13

This is what you need,

```
sudo kextunload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
sudo kextload /System/Library/Extensions/AppleHDA.kext
```

But if you want to kill your coreaudio as well,

```
 ps aux | grep 'coreaudio[d]' | awk '{print $2}' | xargs sudo kill
```

use with caution.
The `grep` target is written this way specifically to exclude grepping the `grep` process itself in the `ps` out.

Comment: The driver loading/unloading is the only thing that worked to make the Mac detect my headphones. THANK YOU!

Comment: The kext changes caused my laptop to reset - I don't recommend it. The fix for me was to go to `Settings > Sound` and check the Output is set correctly.

Comment: @vaughan what is your OSX version? any special hardware? like fancy microphone or speakers or audio devices with specially drivers?

Comment: This temporarily brings back my sound.  In my case, I have had audio issues ever since using a Plantronics USB headset that was provided to test Cisco Jabber.  Reloading the AppleHDA kext provides temporary sound but video still lags and stutters.

Comment: @Aron you much have some software (driver) installed that (on boot?) replaces or changes things back. Ideally they also provided you with an uninstaller that removes that faulty software/driver.

Comment: Works. I had to kill coreaudio first, probably because a track was playing - should've stopped it first. MacBook Pro 13, late 2013, 10.10.1

Comment: @Ali why 'coreaudio[d]' and not just 'coreaudiod'?

Comment: @dev I remember (at least at the time, I guess it was snow leopard?) there were also other processes running, that will get stuck and their name started with `coreaudio` but at least on El Capitan it looks they may not be present.

Comment: @Ali but I mean from a regexp point of view, isn't `coreaudio[d]` exactly the same as `coreaudiod`? (ie a bracket expression with only one character is equivalent to that single character)

Comment: @dev you are correct. It must have had a `*` at the end or something. Don't  really remember. Maybe got deleted in editing or something. Good catch.

Comment: Using builtin speaker and this fixed when VLC caused all output to become silent. But also it caused volume control not to work.

Comment: Just restarting core audio solved my problem... whatever my problem was.   My system just hung for 10s or so and then recovered except for sound.   OS X: 10.11.5 -- but volume control doesn't work.   Reloading kext's fixed it all the way.

Comment: (kernel) Can't unload kext com.apple.driver.AppleHDA; classes have instances:
(kernel)     Kext com.apple.driver.AppleHDA class AppleHDATDMBusManager has 1 instance.
(kernel)     Kext com.apple.driver.AppleHDA class AppleHDATDMBusManagerCS4208 has 2 instances.
Failed to unload com.apple.driver.AppleHDA - (libkern/kext) kext is in use or retained (cannot unload).

Comment: That is great, thanks. It happens most times I do not disconnect my bluetooth headphone properly, so I have bound those commands to an alias of restartAudio in my .zsh_profile !

Comment: Thanks @ali it finally saved me a daily restart I had for the past 3 months of my life!

Comment: I get the same error messages as @Sergei. After doing so, my sound is completely disabled. The icon is grayed out, the function keys don't work. I have to reboot to bring everything back.

Comment: Follow-up question if it does not work on High Sierra [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/401554/how-to-get-sound-back-after-kextunload-applehda-kext-on-high-sierra).

Answer (score 100):

Try typing this into Terminal:

> sudo killall coreaudiod

This will kill the coreaudio process and restart it.

Comment: This is exactly what I was hoping for! ...but it doesn't seem to work.  Upon executing the command I see all the internal audio devices disappear and reappear in Audio/MIDI setup, but the external interface does not appear with them. I also tried `killall -KILL` and `killall -ABRT` which have the same result. Perhaps something similar but lower-level needs to be done, like restarting/reloading all usb devices?

Comment: This fixed my no sound effects problem.

Comment: wow my issue was the internal speakers would stop working intermittently until i rebooted. thanks! this did the trick!

Comment: Did not restart for me. Sound is just off/disabled now.

Comment: Did not restart for me as well. Any specific command to start it ?

Comment: @sequoiamcdowell This should work: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/187983/sudo-killall-coreaudiod-made-it-so-i-dont-have-any-volume-at-all

Comment: Some applications do not handle the audio daemon going away very well. For example, iTunes may just show a grayed out volume control until you restart it.

Comment: this is the correct answer for 10.13, my issue seems to be caused by Spotify.

Comment: why is this answer so low - it works for me? Spotify may also be the culprit for me.

Comment: This worked like a charm for me on macOS Mojave (10.14.6 (18G6032)).

Answer (score 19):

The "proper" way to restart coreaudiod is this: `sudo launchctl kickstart -kp system/com.apple.audio.coreaudiod`

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me on Catalina.

Comment: Big Sur as well

Comment: Monterey too. Nothin else worked.

Comment: Thanks! Worked on my M1 Pro (Monterey).

Comment: Helps for when Core Audio Driver (SoundID Reference.driver) is unloaded on Ventura for some reason.

Comment: This Killed my sound completely, could not connect to airPods anymore. I then had to execute killall coreaudiod to make the sound work again but it was stuttering still. (Ventura)

Comment: @Silv I experienced that a long time ago and it was a bluetooth issue. You can reset bluetooth and then do this if needed.

Answer (score 4):

Same solution but with different variation

```
sudo kill -9 `ps ax|grep 'coreaudio[a-z]' | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Comment: Don't use `kill -9` just for the sake of it. A bare `kill` is perfectly sufficient to halt the daemon in normal circumstances. Indiscriminate use of `-9` can lead to situations where a daemon shuts down so brutally that you can no longer restart it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same interface and that happened to me a lot when I first got it.

I thought the audio drivers in my Mac were the problem, but it was just the way I plugged in the interface.

Every time I wanted to use it, I had to unplug it and plug it back into the computer.

Answer (score -2):

Here I have discovered that if I select another device before disconnecting the interface (Fast Track C400 too), I can connect it again later with no problem. But if I am using the fast track and then disconnect it, it can't connect again until restart it.